# SSL Error from eb init (Elastic Beanstalk) to deploy Flask application

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli, ebcli

The SSL error says the following from running eb init (for deploying an Elastic Beanstalk environment for a web application):

```
ERROR: SSLError - SSL validation failed for https://elasticbeanstalk.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)
```

The certificate issue likely comes from my work computer's VPN (Zscaler) blocking default ca certificates. I had fixed SSL errors on this device in the past by pointing certificate validation to a Zscaler certificate on my device, but cannot figure out how to fix this issue from ebcli.

I have tried to create a named profile in the aws config file (found in /home/.aws) and running the command with the profile field.

```
eb init --profile eb-cli
```

where /home/.aws/config:

```
[profile eb-cli]
aws_access_key_id = xxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxx
region = us-west-2
output = json
ca_bundle = my-cert-path\zscaler-cert.pem
```

I also had my elastic beanstalk config file point to this aws named profile. /home/project/.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml:

```
global:
  profile: eb-cli
```

I also tried to set the ca bundle manually:

```
set AWS_CA_BUNDLE=my-cert-path/zscaler-cert.pem
```

What is interesting is that an awscli command which also requires ssl validation runs without error.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-west-2
```

It seems that awscli is able to find and recognize the new certificate file, however ebcli (namely with eb init) is not. I was under the impression that aws and eb config files were interchangeable, or at least that an aws named profile was a legitimate way to configure an eb environment before deployment. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> SSL validation failed for https://elasticbeanstalk.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/

The domain:

```
elasticbeanstalk.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

is not yours. It **belogs to AWS**, and you can't setup any valid SSL certificates for it. To have HTTPS in your EB website, you have to have **your own domain**, for which you get SSL cert. More information is in aws docs:

- [Configuring HTTPS for your Elastic Beanstalk environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html)